# Proof that two sequences converge to the same limit

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $ x_n $ be a convergent sequence.
Show that the sequence $ y_n $ with

$y_n = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n}{n}, \ n \in \mathbb{N}$

also converges to the same limit.

We can rewrite $y_n$ as $\frac{x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n}{n} = \frac{1}{n}(x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n)$. This represents the average of the first $n$ terms of $(x_n)$.

As $n \to \infty$, the arithmetic mean of the sequence $x_n$ approaches $L$. Therefore, $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n}{n} = L$.

What should I do in next step?

Comment: Fix $\epsilon>0$, show that if $n$ is large enough, then $x_n \approx L$ and argue that $y_n \approx L$

Comment: I don't understand how to do it